# Using base64 to send binary files to a browser

Tags: java, streaming, base64, lotus-domino

I was writing a code to create an Excel file using Java POI. My app runs on Lotus Domino Server. There is no way in domino to stream the created excel file which resides on the hard disk to stream to the output. There is a printwriter output, which writes to the browser, but it works with text. I thought of a workaround, where I will convert the excel file into Base64 text and write it to the output printwriter. But is there anyway I can specify that the content is actually an Excel file in Base64 format. I can use content-type but what about encoding. I have a strong belief that this is blunder, but please help.

Regards,
Anoop

Answer (score 1):

According to this [article](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/explore-ways-to-pass-a-microsoft-excel-file-to-the-client-side/5072712), you can send it to the browser as an html table, setting the mime type to "application/vnd.ms-excel"

Answer (score 1):

Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel
Transfer-Encoding: base64

You should be able to accomplish this pretty much directly with the MIME routines.  I haven't looked at them in-depth, but they spend a good deal of time talking about the application/* MIME encoding translations.